# Gson: NoSuchMethodException for Android 4.2.2 devices

Tags: android, gson

I am getting a strange issue/exception NoSuchMethodException for JellyBean (4.2.2) devices on my production version. Attached the screenshot of stack trace.

Here is my version of Gson:

```
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
```

I am getting this error every-time I try to call `gson.fromJson` or `gson.toJson`.

[image]

Here is my dependency tree:

```
+--- project :Scratch
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1
|         |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0 -> 1.1.1
|         |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1
|         |              |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |              +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.1
|         |              |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0 -> 1.1.1
|         |    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1 (*)
|         |    |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.1 (*)
|         |    |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.1 (*)
|         |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0 -> 1.1.1
|         |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|              +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
|              \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0
+--- com.android.support:design:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1 -> 27.1.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0 -> 3.9.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0 -> 2.3.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7 -> 2.8.1
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1
|    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1 (*)
|    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.1 (*)
|    +--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1 (*)
|    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1
|    |    +--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.1 (*)
|    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1 (*)
+--- com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2
+--- com.github.jinatonic.confetti:confetti:1.1.0
+--- com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0
+--- com.blankj:utilcode:1.9.8
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0
|    \--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0 -> 2.3.0 (*)
+--- io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+ -> 2.18.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 27.1.1
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:11.4.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.4.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:11.4.2
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:11.4.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:11.4.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid-license:11.4.2
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm-license:11.4.2
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.4.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.4.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:11.4.2
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:11.4.2
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.4.2 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-license:11.4.2
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.4.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.4.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.4.2 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-license:11.4.2
+--- com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.3.0
+--- me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2 -> 27.1.1
+--- de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0 -> 27.1.1
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1
+--- jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.7
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.4.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.4.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.3
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.5
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17
|    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.17
|    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17
|    |    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.13
|    |         \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17
|    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.13 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.0
+--- me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2
+--- it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.15
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0
|    +--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.6.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.jakewharton:kotterknife:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.4-3 -> 1.2.41
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.github.developer-shivam:Crescento:1.2.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:palette-v7:25.0.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- project :luhn
|    +--- com.android.support:design:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1
|    \--- uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0
|         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- project :tooltip
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0 -> 27.1.1
+--- com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.6
|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.github.freshdesk:freshchat-android:1.3.1
|    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0 -> 2.8.1
|    +--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.4.2
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.4.2 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:11.4.2
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl-license:11.4.2
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-license:11.4.2
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.41
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.41 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1
+--- com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5
|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
```

Comment: Are you using ProGuard? It's probably wrecking your code.

Comment: Ofcourse I am using Proguard. Can you help me with the settings of proguard for Google Gson that can remove the above crash @EricCochran

Comment: is it happening only in 4.2.2 ?

Comment: Yes @SachinVarma

Comment: Will the proguard settings for gson help me in the above issue ? @SachinVarma If yes then why they are not giving me crash on versions other than 4.2.2.

Comment: I just saw that my proguard settings for GSON were missing. Will it really make a difference, then how the app is not crashing on other versions

Comment: As per i know, proguard will not depend upon the OS versions, so if it is working above 4.2.2 means, this may not be the reason, but you can try it out.

Comment: @SachinVarma Got it

Comment: working with Gson proguarding??

Comment: @SachinVarma I dont have the version 4.0 device or the emulator with me right now. Will have to check it with a long process. will revert you asap

Comment: Ok sure, just un-deleted my answer, let me know whether it helped or not.

Comment: It would be interesting to know which type the class actually represents!

Comment: are you using multidex?

Comment: Could you show the dependency tree? I've faced this problem some times due transitive dependencies using different version of the same lib.

Comment: @Michael. yes I am using Multidex

Comment: @ilopezluna will update the same in my question. This type of crash is happening with one device model only. alps-> Techno R7

Comment: @SachinVarma App is still crashing after proguard settings :p

Comment: Sorry mahn, Someone else may help you out. :)

Comment: Post your data classes that this happens to (the models that use GSON)

Comment: Can you provide sample json that you are trying to convert

Comment: @SahilManchanda I can post anything but this is only happening with one type of device 'Techno R7'. Is it possible with Android version 4.2.2

Comment: @ilopezluna dependency tree updated in question

Comment: Your project have multiple versions of `com.google.code.gson`. From the dependency tree I see you are using the following versions: `2.7`, `2.8.0`and `2.8.1`. Seems like your are using the `2.8.1` version (remember: on runtime you are using only one version), so I would try forcing one specific version on Gradle. I would try forcing the oldest (`2.7` on your case). This kind of problems are due the version used on runtime has no some method present on another version.

Comment: @ilopezluna can you help me to solve the version issue regarding the same ?

Comment: should I use like this :




configurations.all { 
    resolutionStrategy.force com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
}

@ilopezluna

Comment: You can exclude the transitive dependencies `com.google.code.gson` or force your project to use an specific version. I guess you will get the same result. Take a look at: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html

Comment: Maybe is something similar to Xiaomi device problem with commons-lang3 library where firmware has older version of library than yours in the app, and it is forced to use older one because of the same package names? Can you try to force using your version of gson library with -keepnames class com.google.code.gson.** { *; } and to try it like that?

Answer (score 1):

We had problem like this. Try to use JarJar Tool https://github.com/pantsbuild/jarjar and repack code from com.google.code.gson package to com.google.code.gsonlocal for example. Sometime manufacturers include some popular libs in his OS builds and in runtime developers get problems. Repack was only way to solve this problem.

Good luck!